# catch nodejs ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, error-handling, port

So basically, I have the following situation going on: I have a nodejs server running on port 80 and an apache server on port 8080 (the apache server is used for executing php files to a mysql database).

Everything is working fine, unless the nodejs server is down. The client can't get the main index.html file (or any file for that matter) , and therefore can't execute code which includes catching an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error, thrown by the client. When the server is down, I would like to reroute the client to a page with the port :8080 behind the url, where the users can see that the server is down.

My question is how do I do this?

Thank you very kindly,

Zeno

EDIT: apache error:

`[Sat May 23 22:09:46.096365 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5020:tid 324] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 23 22:09:46.112376 2015] [proxy_html:notice] [pid 5020:tid 324] AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characters in proxied pages are likely to display incorrectly.
[Sat May 23 22:09:46.189482 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5020:tid 324] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat May 23 22:09:46.195484 2015] [proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 5020:tid 324] AH01177: Failed to lookup provider 'shm' for 'slotmem': is mod_slotmem_shm loaded??
[Sat May 23 22:09:46.195484 2015] [:emerg] [pid 5020:tid 324] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify a fallback resource in cases where one resource is not available:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This can be placed in an .htaccess file or within your apache config.

https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/

To handle the node server being down, you would need to have setup a reverse proxy server using apache or nginx.  Then you can specify a fallback resource in case the place your proxy points to is down.

This is how to setup a reverse proxy in apache with fallback via balancer.
https://serverfault.com/q/87507/193671

Comment: well, the apache server isn't called when users connect to the main page, so I guess the apache config never gets called. When I type something like "localhost:8080/kjfkj" in the url bar, I get redirected thanks to the fallbackResource line you gave me, but when I try to connect to the nodejs server (which isn't online) I don't get redirected.

Comment: Reverse proxy to the node server and specify a fallback.

Comment: So, I did the proxypass thing, but I still have the same problem... When the nodejs server isn't running, the website still doesn't load..

Comment: So do I write: `ProxyPass / balancer://hotcluster/
<Proxy balancer://hotcluster>
 BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 timeout=15 retry=300
 BalancerMember http://localhost status=+H
</Proxy>` Or `<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName camera.example.com
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPass / balancer://hotcluster/
   <Proxy balancer://hotcluster>
       BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 timeout=15 retry=300
       BalancerMember http://localhost status=+H
   </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
`? Either way is giving me a 500 internal server error...

Comment: Do you have the module enabled? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Comment: yeah, I forgot that... I tried again, but now the apache won't start up... Still working on finding the error... And by the way, do I have to write only the <proxy balancer> and <proxypass>? Or do I have to write that in the <virtualhost> ? EDIT: I wrote the error in the description above

Comment: hmmm. I redid what I previously did and checked all my steps for possible errors, and it actually seems that the proxy_balancer_module is causing apache to crash at startup... any thoughts?

Comment: Check the apache error log. Maybe missing dependency.

Comment: yes... It seemed like I needed another module to be loaded... it is at least starting now. I'll report back to you when I run into other problems (thanks for your very kind help btw)

Comment: So, I am stuck again... 3 situations occur: 1) if in the httpd.conf is one balancermember: localhost:8080 and the server is online: everything works except loading php files. 2) When both the balancermembers (localhost:8080 and localhost:80) are in the config, if the nodejs server is online then everything works like 1) but if the nodejs server is down I get a 503 error. 3) When balancermember localhost:80 is the only one in the config, I get the same 503 error.